# Performing async operation for arrays in a NodeRed function

Tags: node.js, asynchronous, node-red

I'm currently writing a function to parse some incoming JSON data and displaying them as charts.
In order to do that, I'm using a for loop and populating JSON data in an array like this.

```
var allMsg = [];

async.each (jsonData.dataSet,
  function (sensorItem, callback) {
    for each item in array .... {
      var msg1 = {};
      msg1.req = msg.req;
      msg1.res = msg.res;
      msg1.payload = "some payload";
      allMsg.push(msg1);
    }
    callback();
  },
  function(err) {
    node.send([allMsg];
  }
};
return;
}
```

Above example only send first element which is allMsg[0].
I know that to handle async operations you need to do node.send as opposed to return msg, but I'm just not quite sure where I should do node.send 
If anyone can help, that'd be super great... Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the example given you would need to declare a function to pass as the `callback` argument to the `each`

The other option is to just publish each message as it's created rather than push them to the `allMsg` array. e.g.

```
async.each (jsonData.dataSet,
  function (sensorItem, callback) {
    for each item in array .... {
      var msg1 = {};
      msg1.req = msg.req;
      msg1.res = msg.res;
      msg1.payload = "some payload";
      node.send(msg1);
    }
  },
  function(err) {
    //node.send([allMsg];
  }
};
```

But it looks like you are using this function node between a pair of `http-in` and `http-response` nodes (msg.res/msg.req). This will not work because the `http-response` will only reply with the first message it receives, you can not stream multiple messages this way. You could use a `join` node to wait for all the results to complete if needed.

Comment: OK could this be better suited to node.send for each msg1?
I have http-in -> this function -> switch -> 10 charts 
If I use join, then could I put join between switch and charts to combine the msgs?

Comment: That's what the second suggestion on the answer says